# Search SQL Server rows to find if record included in the search string using ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I need to search a table to find if a bad word is found in the user's form input. So I have created a function to apply to each of the form inputs, and that function checks the database table to compare it to the input string.

This is actually the opposite to the usual requirement where one might be searching records to find the inclusion of a keyword. For that one can use...

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM MailBlock WHERE Keyword LIKE '%" + Replace(strInputString, "'", "''") + "%' "
```

Instead I want to find the inclusion of the "record" in the "search string". For example one of the database records might be "spam" so when a user submits an email address like "me@spam.me" then it will be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option that does work using ASP. It doesn't identify which keyword was triggered to be able to report a message that may be associated/recorded for the keyword, but it does check to see if every keyword might be included in the form's input string...

```
Function CheckMailBlock(mailString)
if mailString <> "" then    
    SQLMailBlock = "SELECT * FROM MailBlock Where MailBlock.Active = '1' "
    Set rsMailBlock = dbConnection.Execute(SQLMailBlock)
    if not rsMailBlock.EOF then         
        Do Until rsMailBlock.EOF
            strMailKeyword = rsMailBlock("Keyword").value
            If Instr(1, mailString, strMailKeyword, 1) <> "0" Then
                strMailBlockFound = strMailBlockFound & "1"
            End If
        rsMailBlock.MoveNext
        Loop
    end if
    rsMailBlock.Close
    Set rsMailBlock = Nothing
end if
    CheckMailBlock = strMailBlockFound
End Function

if CheckMailBlock(strInputString) then
    'cancel submission and do stuff
    strMessage = "Your submission was not acceptible!"
end if
```

If a keyword is found in the string the results will be 1. If a 2nd keyword is found the result will be 11, so any result greater than 0 means that the keyword was found.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know your tag is asp-classic, but its probably a good thing to use appropriate technology for the relevant problem. I would suggest you use jquery to do a client side validation. Like this:

```
if (str.indexOf("BadWord") >= 0)
```

If you want a case-insensitive search, you can write

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("badword") >= 0)
```

Your list of badWords can be derived from a server side query of a table look up, or  hard coded.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is for Classic ASP. JavaScript won't be appropriate. Yes, using a hard coded list would make it easy, but a hardcoded list cannot be updated as simply as a table can be updated from a web form.

Comment: Well horses for courses, you obviously know the reason why, but it certanly isnt technical...here on using jQuery with classic asp.  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/98/Ajax-with-Classic-ASP-using-jQuery

Comment: JavaScript cannot change anything here. SQL still has to be queried and that is where the solution lays. Querying with JS as VBscript is still ASP.